# Tail bounds on Euclidean norm for uniform distribution on $\{-n,-(n-1),...,n-1,n\}^d$

Tags: uniform-distribution, extreme-value, bounds

What are known upper bounds on how often the Euclidean norm of a uniformly chosen
element of $\:\{-n,~-(n-1),~...,~n-1,~n\}^d\:$ will be larger than a given threshold?

I'm mainly interested in bounds that converge exponentially to zero when $n$ is much less than $d$.

Comment: This is easy to answer for thresholds $t\le n$--you're just computing volumes of hyperspheres--but more difficult to work out for $t \gt n$. Are you in either of those situations?

Comment: I would need $\: t > n \;\;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I don't have time to post a detailed answer at the moment, but here is a hint in the meantime: Compare $\sum_k (X_k/n)^2$ to a binomial random variable with the same mean employing the standard Chernoff bound technique. This will yield a bound of the form $a^d e^{-b t^2}$ for appropriate $a$ and $b$ provided $t > n \sqrt{d (n+1)/3n}$ which makes sense once you think about what the mean of the squared Euclidean distance is. Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it should be obvious that a point whose coordinates are sampled at random from the uniform distribution should have small modulus due to the curse of dimensionality. As $d$ increases, the probability that a point sampled at random from the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit ball will have distance less than or equal to $\epsilon$ from the center is $\epsilon^{d}$, which drops exponentially fast.

I'll give the full version of cardinal's solution.

Let $X_i$ be one independent copy of a discrete, uniform distribution over the integers $-n \leqslant k \leqslant n$.  Clearly, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$, and it is [easily computed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282n%2B1%29+%2a+sum+i+%3D+-n...n+%28i+-+0%29%5E2) that $\text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$

Recall that $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \text{Var}(X_i) + \mathbb{E}[X_i]^2$ and that $\text{Var}(X_i^2) =  \mathbb{E}[X_i^4] - \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]^2$

Thus, $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$

$\text{Var}(X_i^2) =  \mathbb{E}[X_i^4] - \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(3n^2 + 3n + 1)}{15} - \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{3} \right)^2$

[$\mathbb{E}[X_i^4]$ computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/%282n%2b1%29%20%2a%20sum%20i%20=%20-n...n%20%28i%20-%200%29%5E4)

Let $Y_i = X_i^2$

$$\sum_{i=1}^d Y_i = (\text{Distance of Randomly Sampled Point to Origin})^2$$

I'll finish this tomorrow, but you can see that this variable has a mean of about $\frac{n^2}{3}$, while less than $2^{-d}$ fraction of points have distances less than half the maximum distance $\frac{dn^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If all $X_i$ follow independent discrete uniforms over $[-n, n]$, then as there are $2n+1$ values to choose from and their mean is 0, we have for all $i$:

$\mathbb{E}(X_i)= 0$, and

$\mathbb{V}(X_i)= \mathbb{E}\left((X_i - \mathbb{E}(X_i))^2\right)= \mathbb{E}(X_i^2)= \frac{(2n+1)^2 - 1}{12}= \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$

Then if $S$ is the squared euclidean norm of vector $(X_1, X_2, ... X_d)$, and because of the independence of the $X_i$:

$S= \sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2$

$\mathbb{E}(S)= \sum_{i=1}^d \mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = d \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$

From here on you could use Markov's inequality: $\forall a >0, \mathbb{P}(S \geq a) \leq \frac{1}{a}\mathbb{E}(S)$

$\mathbb{P}(S \geq a) \leq \frac{d}{a}\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$

This bound rises with $d$, which is normal because when $d$ gets larger the euclidean norm gets larger when compared to a fixed threshold $a$.

Now if you define $S^*$ as a "normalized" squared norm (that has the same expected value no matter how big $d$) you get:

$S^*= \frac{1}{d} Y = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2$

$\mathbb{E}(S^*) = \frac{n(n+1)}{3} $

$\mathbb{P}(S \geq a) \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{3a}$

At least this bound doesn't rise with $d$, but it still far from solves your quest for an exponentially decreasing bound! I wonder if this can be due to the weakness of the Markov inequality...

I think you should precise your question, because as stated above the mean euclidean norm of your vectors linearly rises in $d$, so you are very unlikely to find an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(S > a)$ that is decreasing in $d$ with a fixed threshold $a$.